# Attaching library to form isn't working

Tags: 8, forms

I'm using hook_form_alter.  I'm having a weird situation where attaching my library works only if I do what I would think is incorrect:

`$form['#attached']['library'] = array('somemodule/somelibrary');`

But not if I do this:

`$form['#attached']['library'][] = array('somemodule/somelibrary');`

What could cause a thing like this?  I debugged to see what was happening in the FormBuilder, but it seems like the library is added either way.  It's not removed by any other module or anything.

Comment: Note that you have to add the module / theme name before the library name: `core/drupal`, `foo_module/bar_library`

Comment: Yes, I just changed the library's name for the example, I'll update the question so it follows that format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those two statements are not equal.

`$form['#attached']['library'] = array('somelibrary');`

Resets the library array to only contain "somelibrary".  This would remove anyone else's library that may need to get loaded.

`$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'somelibrary';`

This adds "somelibrary" to the existing libraries array for inclusion. (this is correct)

`$form['#attached']['library'][] = array('somelibrary');`

This is the wrong structure.

**For Drupal 8**

`$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'somemodule/somelibrary';`

Comment: Plus, don't you need the format name/library?

Comment: No, just the machine name.  I think the key doesn't matter.

Comment: Correct answer, but yes, you definitely need module/library-name.

Comment: Is that a drupal 8 update?

Comment: See: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module

Comment: Yes, that is a D8 change